# How can I vertically align a webfont and text of different heights

Tags: html, css

Got two buttons that I want to have an icon and text in.

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="button">
        <i class="flaticon-tools6"></i>
        <p>View all services</p>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <div class="button">
        <i class="flaticon-phone16"></i>
        <p>Get a quote</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.button .flaticon-phone16,
.button .flaticon-tools6 {
font-size: 30px;
line-height:42px;
}

.button p {
display: inline;
line-height:42px;
margin: 0px;
}

.button {
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:normal;
line-height: 42px;
height:42px;
width:100%;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
padding: 0;
}
```

I removed the styling stuff from the button class. Currently they are not vertically centered, as visible in this screenshot.

Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

remove the other line-hight and only add line-height with a display block on

```
.button p {display: block; margin: 0px; line-height: 42px; }
```

Comment: That puts the text onto a new line, underneath the icon

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-cell` combine with `vertical-align: middle`:

```css
a {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.button .flaticon-phone16, .button .flaticon-tools6 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.button p {
    margin: 0px;
}
.button {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    line-height: 42px;
    height:42px;
    width:100%;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <div class="button">
        <i class="flaticon-tools6"></i>
        <p>View all services</p>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <div class="button">
        <i class="flaticon-phone16"></i>
        <p>Get a quote</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: That aligned it correctly but now the button does not spread across the whole column width

Comment: check update code. Add display `table` on parent element (`a`) in your case and `width: 100%;`.